# Error Running MVC Application in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When I ran MVC application on visual studio 2013 for the first time, I got error

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 41 in res://nvqsy.dll/BOOTSTRAP/BODY

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'BgScript' is undefined

```
<HTML><title>BGSCR</title><body><SCRIPT>eval(BgScript);
```

I'm gratefull for the Help.

Comment: Well... It's undefined. What more information do you need?

Comment: But. why it's undefined? I just ran default (internet) application MVC for the first time, and got that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BgScript` is not known currently. You will need to emit a value for `BgScript` before you pass it to eval. It's hard to say *where* that value should be coming from, but you would either need to import another js file which has that value or emit the value via MVC to the script like so:

```
<script>
   var BgScript = '@Model.BgScript';
   eval(BgScript);
</script>
```

The sample code assumes that there is a property `BgScript` available on the model.